# Set <Avatar> backgroundColor randomly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have defined three backgroundColor in the style theme.

```
avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500],
},
orangeAvatar: {
    margin: 10,
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: deepOrange[500],
},
purpleAvatar: {
    margin: 10,
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: deepPurple[500],
},
```

When ever the Avatar is loaded I would like to select one of them randomly.

```
<Card>
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                    <Avatar id="av" aria-label="Recipe"
                        className={classes.avatar}>{this.props.userName.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase()}
                    </Avatar>}
                title={this.props.userName} disableTypography={true}/>
            <CardActionArea disabled={this.state.images.length == 1 ? true : false}>
                <CardMedia
                    id={this.props.ownerId}
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={this.state.images[this.state.imageIndex]}
                    onClick={this.handleOnClick}
                />
            </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
```

Any advice how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several ways to do what you want. My suggestion: put the 3 classes in an array, pick a random number between 0 and 2 every time, and assign that class name:

`<Avatar className={classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]}.../>`

Answer (score 5):

I was presented with the same need, perhaps this solution will also serve you, there is a function to generate the color at random and then call the function from the online style.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    large: {
      fontSize: "2.5rem",
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }
  })
);

function randomColor() {
  let hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
  let color = "#" + hex.toString(16);

  return color;
}
```

...

```
  return (
    <Avatar
      variant="square"
      src={imageSrc}
      alt={alt}
      className={classes.large}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: randomColor()
      }}
    />
  )
```

ref:

[Javascript random color](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/2QNRq/)

[Avatar random backgroundColor on fallback](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19349)

Answer (score 0):

```
let classNameHolder = ["avatar","orangeAvatar","purpleAvatar"];
<Card>
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                    <Avatar id="av" aria-label="Recipe"
                        className={classNameHolder[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]}>{this.props.userName.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase()}
                    </Avatar>}
                title={this.props.userName} disableTypography={true}/>
            <CardActionArea disabled={this.state.images.length == 1 ? true : false}>
                <CardMedia
                    id={this.props.ownerId}
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={this.state.images[this.state.imageIndex]}
                    onClick={this.handleOnClick}
                />
            </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
```

Comment: this is perfect - > {Math.floor(Math.random() * classNameHolder.length}